# Prime pairs $\{ p,q \}$ with $p\neq q$ such that $p-1\mid pq+1$ and $q-1\mid pq+1$.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Find all prime pairs $\{ p,q \}$ with $p\neq q$ such that $p-1\mid pq+1$ and $q-1\mid pq+1$.

I only found 2 pairs: $\{ 3,5 \}$ and $\{ 5,7 \}$.

Are these the only ones?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Write $pq + 1$ as $(p-1)q + (q+1)$ and as $p(q-1) + p+1$ respectively to get divisibility conditions that make answering the question easier.

Comment: ok ...such that `(p-1)|(p−1)q+(q+1)` and `(q-1)|(q−1)p+(p+1)`.

Comment: @MartinHopf I think you missed the point of Daniel's hint.  Once you know $p-1 \mid (p-1)q + (q+1)$ you immediately have $p-1 \mid q+1$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$pq+1\equiv q+1\equiv 0\mod (p-1)$$ and $$pq+1\equiv p+1\equiv 0 \mod (q-1)$$

This implies $p-1\le q+1$ and $q-1\le p+1$, hence $p-2\le q\le p+2$. This shows that the difference between $p$ and $q$ is at most $2$. So, assuming $p\ne q$ , either we have the pair $(2/3)$ which is not a solution or we have a twin-prime-pair, hence $q=p+2$

So, we have $$p+3\equiv 0\mod (p-1)$$ implying $$4\equiv 0\mod (p-1)$$ Hence $p-1$ must divide $4$, so the only possibilities are $p=3$ and $p=5$

Hence there are no more solutions , if $p\ne q$

If $p=q$ would be allowed , we have $p-1|p+1$ implying $p-1|2$, which gives the possibilies $p=2$ and $p=3$, so allowing $p=q$, we get exactly $4$ solutions.

Comment: The title says $p\neq q$, though.

Comment: What is to say about the second pair `(5,7)` as `(5-1)|(5*7+1)` and `(7-1)|(5*7+1)`?

Comment: It corresponds to $p=5$

Comment: thanks, i missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Write $a=p-1$ and $b=q-1$ then $a|ab+a+b+2$ an so $a|b+2$ and thus $a\leq b+2$. Similary we get $b\leq a+2$. Thus $$a\in \{b-2,b-1,b,b+1,b+2\}$$
Now $$p-1\in \{q-3,q-2,q-1,q,q+1\}$$
and thus
$$p\in \{q-2,q-1,q,q+1,q+2\}$$

If $p=q-1$ we get $(2,3)$ and if $p=q+1$ we get $(3,2)$.

If $p=q-2$ we get $p-1|(p+2)p+1$ so $p-1|4p$ and finaly $p-1|4$ so $(p,q)\in\{(5,7),(3,5)\}$.

If $p=q+2$ we get $(p,q)\in\{(7,5),(5,3)\}$.